# HTML 5 Geolocalization doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, safari, geolocation

I have this basic function for indentify the position of the user:

```
function getLocation()
{

if (navigator.geolocation)
{

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showmyPosition, errorCallback);
}
else
{
alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser."); 
}
}

function showmyPosition(position)
{   
document.location.href="/search?lat="+  position.coords.latitude +"&lng="+ position.coords.longitude +"";
}    

function errorCallback(error) {
if (error.code === 1) {
alert("User denied geolocation");
}
}
```

Works fine on Firefox, Chrome and Explorer but doesn't work on Safary (neither on iPhone). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case geolocation is turned off in configuration, it won't work. In addition it requires a [secure (HTTPS) protocol](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/54276). You could also have a look at JS-lib: https://code.google.com/archive/p/geo-location-javascript/